# App - App Call in Twilio

Tags: twilio, voip

I had been trying to sort out how can I make an **app to app** call using Twilio SDK, every time I end up reading the documentation that make me call a Phone number.
Can anyone please guide me towards the right direction ?
I have been following this link for long:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/ios#gather-twlio-account-information

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

With the quick start tutorial that you have been following, there is an example application that can make calls to both phone numbers and to other applications. The key is, instead of setting a phone number when you dial, you can also set another client identity. The quick start server applications for this give the example app a random identity which you can see in the top bar of the app, which you can use in this case.

So, when you type in another client identity, `device.connect` is called with a dictionary with one key, `To`, set to the identity (https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-swift/blob/master/SwiftTwilioClientQuickstart/DialViewController.swift#L165):

```
connection = device.connect(["To":dialTextField.text!], delegate: self)
```

This will then be present in the request that Twilio makes to your TwiML app and, taking [the Ruby example server as our example here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-ruby/blob/master/app.rb#L33-L48), you can then use this identity to return a [TwiML `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) to another [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) (rather than a [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number)).

The key overall is that you set an identity for each of your application users (which is random in the example), you can then call other identities by passing the identity you want to call into `device.connect` and reading that out of the parameters in Twilio's request to your TwiML application. If you then return TwiML to direct Twilio to [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) the [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) with the identity you sent then an app to app call will be made.

Let me know if that helps at all.